# Running Rcpp line-by-line (debug) under macOS (Catalina)

Tags: r, debugging, rcpp

Is there a simple way to run Rcpp line-by-line under macOS to see what the code does?

Comment: Use a debugger? `gdb` with the `gcc` family and `lldb` for the `clang` side.  You may want to look into the latter on that platform.